# How to modify the css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on the following page: http://sya7i.com I know very little CSS so please dumb it down for me.

I would like "flip the square from LTR to RTL".

Thanks.

Comment: `text-align: left` or `direction: rtl` ? Question is really unclear.

Comment: use `direction: rtl;` on `body` to start everything from `right` to `left`.

Comment: if you enter to the web site you will see a square in need to arrange it from RTL,

When i make a inspect element i see this class "block format-standard block-empty grid-sizer" and it has property called left how i can change it to right

Comment: Do you know that you can experiment and change values directly on the inspector, right?

Comment: Yes i know and it is work, the value its in inline i need way to change it from the tamplate CSS file, how i can select the class name ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem you want start everything from `Right` to `Left`

use like this `<body dir="rtl">`.  or use to move specific content from `Right` to `Left`.

```
.main-content {
  direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per our discussion you want to move one box move to `right` so as there is inline CSS in your code. so the only solution is use `!important` which I really don't like.

put this line on your CSS file and I hope it will solve your problem. see a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zeqanaruyiwu/1/edit)**.

```
article.grid-sizer{position:absolute; right:0 !important;top: 120px;}
```

Comment: if you enter to the web site you will see a square in need to arrange it from RTL,

When i make a inspect element i see this class "block format-standard block-empty grid-sizer" and it has property called left how i can change it to right

Comment: how about using `!important` like this in your CSS file. `article.grid-sizer{border:1px solid red; position:absolute; right:0 !important;top: 120px;}`

Comment: I but it in the template CSS file but it does not work !
|| this what i want to change but the name of the class is my propleme who can i know it
element.style {
    left: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
}